# How to prove that series $\frac{1}{n+1}$, as $n\to \infty$ is zero.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Can somebody explain how to prove that series $\frac{1}{n+1}$, as $n \to \infty$? I mean infinite series, not sequence, and I want to understand how to define the partial sum when n goes to infinity. Thank you!

Comment: The series? so you are going to add them? or the sequence?

Comment: I voted to close because as an infinite series, this diverges. Even beyond that you show no effort.

Comment: See this page http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference and type currectly

Comment: @Andrey Andrey, your question is diverge as your series

Comment: $\frac{1}{n+1}\approx\frac{1}{n}$ and apply p-Test you will easily get , the series is divergent

Answer (score 3):

The natural numbers are not bounded (this can be proven by using the fact the real numbers have the least upper bound property). What this means is given a real number $r$ we can find a natural number $N$ so that $N>r$.

We wish to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}=0$. So we have to prove given $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N$ such that if $n\geq N$ then $|0-\frac{1}{n+1}|<\epsilon$ so $\frac{1}{n+1}<\epsilon$

Of course this is equivalent to $n+1>\frac{1}{\epsilon}\iff n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}-1$. Because the natural numbers are not bounded, there is an $N$ that satisfies that inequality. This is the $N$ we need.

Because from $n\geq N$ we have $n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}-1$ and this gives us $\frac{1}{n+1}<\epsilon$ which is what we needed.

---

You changed the problem statement, apparently you want to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i+1}=0$. This is not true, a very simple way to see this is that every term of the series is larger than or equal to $1$, hence given $\epsilon<1$ it will be impossible to find $N$ so that if $n\geq N$ then $|0-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i+1}|<\epsilon$. Since we shall have $|0-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i+1}|\geq 1$.

It can also be proven that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i+1}$ does not exist. I can write the proof if you want.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n{1\over n+1}=1$, actually.

Comment: $1/2+1/3+1/4+1/5+1/6>1$, I don't see how that claim is possible.

Comment: Oh ok I got it. it should be an $i$ instead of an $n$. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}=1$ :)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a conflict between the wording of your question and the notation you wrote.

A sequence is an ordered collection of numbers $$\{ 1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, ... \}$$ and a series is the sum of a sequence $$1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + \cdots = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}.$$

The series is divergent, but the sequence converges to zero. I will prove both of these in this post.

---

In order to prove that the sequence converges to zero, we must show that for any given real number $\epsilon >0$, the sequence is smaller than $\epsilon$ for large enough $n$.

We will prove this by contradiction, this means we will assume the opposite of what we wish to prove and demonstrate that something will go wrong. To this end, suppose that there is an $\epsilon >0$ for which given any $N$ we can find a $n > N$ so that $$\frac{1}{n} > \epsilon > 0.$$

This means that $$1 > \epsilon \cdot n > 0$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, since once we have $\epsilon > 1/N$ we know that $\epsilon > 1/n$ for all $n > N$ . This is where something breaks. The real numbers have a property called the Archimedian property. This says given any two positive real numbers $r > s$ there is an integer $N$ for which $Ns > r$. The fact that $1 > \epsilon \cdot n$ for all $n$ violates this property.

Thus for each $\epsilon$, there is an $n$ for which $\epsilon > 1/n > 0$, and since $1/n > 1/m$ for $m>n$, this means that $\epsilon > 1/m$ for all $m > n$. Thus for all large enough $n$ we are smaller than $\epsilon >0$. This is what is required to demonstrate convergence to zero.

---

In order to demonstrate that the series diverges, we have a couple of options. The classical proof goes back to Oresme in the 1300s. He observed that $$1 + \frac12 + \frac13 + \frac14 + \frac15 + \frac16 + \frac17 + \frac18 + \cdots $$ $$ \ge 1 + \frac12 + \left(\frac14 + \frac14\right) + \left(\frac18 + \frac18 + \frac18 + \frac18\right) + \cdots$$
$$ \ge 1 + \frac12 + \left( \frac12 \right) + \left( \frac12 \right) + \cdots$$

Where the right hand side becomes the series $$1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac12 = \infty.$$ This was the first use of what we call the comparison test today. We can make the argument more formal using partial sums:

Note that the sequence of partial sums $$S_N = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}$$ is increasing. If we can show that a subsequence converges to infinity, the whole sequence must also, since it is increasing.

Consider $$S_{2^N} = 1 + \frac12 + \frac13 + \frac14 + \cdots + \frac1{2^N}$$
as we saw above we can compare this to:
$$1 + \frac12 + \left( \frac14 + \frac14 \right) + \left( \frac18 + \frac18 + \frac18 + \frac18 \right) + \cdots + \left(\frac{1}{2^N} + \frac1{2^N} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^N}\right)=1+N\cdot \frac12.$$

Thus $$S_{2^N} > 1+ N \cdot \frac12$$ and the right hand side goes to infinity. Now we know that $S_{2^N} \to \infty$. We may conclude that $S_N$ also diverges, since it is an increasing sequence. This the series diverges.

As an aside, this series is known as the Harmonic series, and it appears frequently in a lot of applications. In particular, it plays a big role in computer science and the study of computer algorithms.